# Create a function that can call another function in the same line, as if it was a return value, in JS

Tags: javascript

Imagine you have this class

```
class Dog{
  eat(dogName){
   ...
  }
}
```

Then you create the object and call the eat function

```
let doggy = new Dog();
doggy.eat('Max');
```

How can i nest a floss function for example inside of the eat one so that i could call that function right after eat

```
let doggy = new Dog();
doggy.eat('Max').floss();
```

I want the call to the floss function to be optional, so i could call floss whenever i needed only.

If i return this within the eat function i would still need to add the dog's name inside the floss function and that's not what i'm looking for.

```
doggy.eat('Max').floss('Max');
```

I want the eat function to call the floss function and to pass the dog's name variable without having to write it explicitly in the floss function.

Comment: Is `floss` a function in the `Dog` class like `eat`? If yes, then you should add `return this;` to your `eat` function. This will return the instance of the Dog class on which you can then call the `floss` function: `doggy.eat().floss();`

Comment: That solved my previous issue but i'm searching for another solution, i updated the question

Answer (score -1):

Since this seems to be a fluid question..

You are passing 'Max' as a parameter to, what looks like, define a property of a `Dog`.

Wouldn't the following be a more logical, object oriented, approach?

```
let doggy = new Dog(); // we have a new Dog
doggy.Name = "Max"; // his name is Max
doggy.eat(); // Max eats.
doggy.eat().floss(); // Max eats and flosses.
doggy.eat('Tom'); // Max eats Tom, the resulting instance of a Dog is still Max.
// This keeps the function pure.
```

Example of `Floss` function:

```
floss(){
   let name = this.Name; // 'Max'
}
```

This way you 'keep' the variable and make it available in the other function in a clean way; storing the information in the object.

---

Old answer:

Lets say `eat` exists of chewing, swallowing and flossing.
This is how you would define it:

```
class Dog{
  eat(){
    chew(); // calling chew
    swallow();
    floss();
  }

  chew(){ // defining chew
  }

  swallow(){
  }

  floss(){
  }
}
```

It is also possible to keep returning the instance like:

```
class Dog{
  chew(){ // defining chew
    return this;
  }

  swallow(){
    return this;
  }

  floss(){
    return this;
  }
}
```

Leading to

```
let doggy = new Dog();
doggy.chew().swallow().floss();
```

Comment: That's not the exact way i want it to work, i updated the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Gabri answer updated to reflect new question.